# Oh My Zsh - Disable 'Would you like to check for updates' prompt

Tags: command-line, zsh

Every time I open up terminal on a Mac I get the prompt

> Would you like to check for updates?

I find it quite annoying. Anyway to stop it from doing so?

Comment: I am curious on how to make the update unattended instead of diabling it.

Comment: It's not only annoying. It just obliterated my original .zshrc file without even making a back-up.

Comment: @sorin Three years later, here it is. Refer to my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69801730/10830091). `zstyle ':omz:update' mode auto`

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You have to add `DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"` on your `.zshrc` before the `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` line. By doing so, oh-my-zsh will just skip the update checking script.

Answer (score 188):

Set environment variable `DISABLE_UPDATE_PROMPT=true` to always reply **Yes** and automatically upgrade.

Set environment variable `DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE=true` to always reply **No** and never upgrade.

Simply add one of these in your `~/.zshrc` somewhere before calling `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`.

Comment: Is there a way to make the prompt less frequent without disabling it?

Comment: There is a `UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS` variable as well. That accepts an integer to specify a frequency in days.

Comment: (as of this comment) All of these settings are now available in your `~/.zshrc` (with comments!).

Comment: `DISABLE_UPDATE_PROMPT=true` should be the default out of box. I probably will ditch ohmyzsh one day b/c of this anoyance.

Answer (score 42):

## Deprecation in some other answers

Other answers might reference deprecated method for updating the settings.

As per OhMyZsh wiki, there is a section talking about [`Deprecated settings`](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Settings#deprecated-settings).

> These settings are still supported but will be removed in a future
> version of Oh My Zsh. Migrate to the `zstyle` settings while you still
> can.

For example, the following two methods achieve the same result:

##### A. Deprecated method for modifying Settings (Environment Variable in `.zshrc`)

```sh
DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE=true
```

##### B. Recommended method for modifying Settings (`zstyle` Setting)

```sh
zstyle ':omz:update' mode disabled
```

I'm surprised no one mentioned the new and fine-tuned controls over OhMyZsh updates, that deprecates the old method.

**This of course does not prevent you from invoking `zstyle` from `.zshrc`.**

You can try the following commands that are stated by OMZ docs:

## OMZ Docs -- [Getting Updates](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh#getting-updates)

You have several options to tweak OMZ updates.

- By default, you will be prompted to check for updates every 2 weeks. You can choose other update modes by adding a line to your ~/.zshrc file, before Oh My Zsh is loaded:
- Automatic update without confirmation prompt:

```sh
zstyle ':omz:update' mode auto
```

- Just offer a reminder every few days, if there are updates available:

```sh
zstyle ':omz:update' mode reminder
```

- **To disable automatic updates entirely**:

```sh
zstyle ':omz:update' mode disabled
```

- NOTE: you can control how often Oh My Zsh checks for updates with the following setting:

```sh
# This will check for updates every 7 days
zstyle ':omz:update' frequency 7
# This will check for updates every time you open the terminal (not recommended)
zstyle ':omz:update' frequency 0
```

### IMPORTANT (`zstyle` precondition)

- Do note, the commands above (`zstyle`) have to be executed strictly from within an OhMyZsh shell.
- In other words, after installing ZSH and OhMyZsh, maybe you decided not to change your default shell to ZSH.
- In that particular case, you have to switch your shell temporarily to ZSH for the above commands to work. You can do that with `exec /bin/zsh`, this probably applies to `.zshrc` as well.

### Understanding `zstyle`

- WARNING: This is a potential rabbit hole :)
- [Online documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fzutil-Module)
- man pages: `man zshmodules`
- Check out some insightful answers in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214657/what-does-zstyle-do).

Comment: How interesting! I wonder if there's any functional or performance difference between using `zstyle` or environment variables in `.zshrc`

Comment: @flyingsandwich that's a good question, I'm not aware of any performance differences. But for functional, using environment variables in `.zshrc` is deprecated and will be removed in the future. `zstyle` is encouraged to be used instead. Here's [the source for that](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Settings#deprecated-settings). Note, that you can invoke and sprinkle `zstyle` in your `.zshrc` file.

Comment: I will update my answer accordingly, I was not aware the environment variables method was deprecated. Thanks!

Comment: One extra functional difference is: **Unlike variables they can be different in different contexts and unlike shell options they can take values** ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/239980))

Comment: The docs leave me with a couple questions - what's the default, `zstyle ':omz:update' frequency 7`? Does the "reminder" mean the update prompt or just a message the prints when you open a shell?

Comment: Oh the docs here answer my questions actually: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Settings#update-settings. Default is "prompt" and reminder is just a reminder

Comment: Exactly @mowwwalker. `reminder` is different from the `prompt` as the former is non-intrusive. I think `reminder` should be the default. No clue why they thought it was a good idea for the `prompt` to be the default.

Answer (score 0):

Go to ~/.oh-my-zsh/tools/check-for-upgrade.sh and replace all contents of this file with

```
true;
```

Everything else seems to be unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

I have set an update on background. My crontab:

```
0 0 * * 0 /bin/zsh -i -c 'omz update' >/dev/null 2>&1
```